# Gnome Shell: show skype icon

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I need to show icons for Skype, Empathy and Dropbox in my system tray (top side). I've read about Gnome Shell extension to show icons in my system tray on the different websites, but this isn't working for me.

I am using: Ubuntu 12.10 + Gnome Shell 3.6.1

[These instructions](http://mo.morsi.org/blog/node/337) haven't helped me (perhaps it was a problem in backwards compatibility changes in Gnome Shell version).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) should work fine.

[image]

Comment: It seems [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) with the same name is better maintained.

Answer (score 1):

For Unity (not Gnome Shell, 17.10+) you could try running

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

Then re-login.

This would make all system tray icons visible

Comment: But this is not Unity panel. This is different project- Gnome Shell, not Unity.

Comment: I've tried this. It is not helped. I have see icon on the bottom panel, but not on the top panel.